# Java, splitting string using string.split with spaces on either side of delimiter

Tags: java, string, split

So I have the following code. I input `"string1 : string2 : string3 : string4"`. I am expecting to get the output `"string2"`, but I get an out of bounds exception error.

I'd like to separate the string contained at the first element of `MasterArray` with space colon space but I don't know how you would go about doing that, in this context.

```
while(true){
    MasterArray[InputNumber] = scan.next(); 

    String parts[] = MasterArray[InputNumber].split(":");

    System.out.print(parts[1]);

    }
```

Comment: `MasterArray[InputNumber] = scan.nextLine(); `

Comment: *FYI:* Java [naming convention](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2697/oracle-official-code-standard/9031/naming-conventions#t=201701011733518383294) states that variable names must start with lowercase letter, so `masterArray` and `inputNumber`. --- If `Scanner` is reading anything other than `System.in` (and even then), you need to change loop to `while (scan.hasNextLine())`. --- It is recommended to put array declaration with the type, so replace `String parts[]` with `String[] parts`, to more accurately indicate that `parts` is a variable of type `String[]`.

Answer (score 0):

**Change scan.next() to scan.nextLine()** It will work for you.

while(true){
    MasterArray[InputNumber] = scan.nextLine();

```
String parts[] = MasterArray[InputNumber].split(":");

System.out.print(parts[1]);

}
```

scan.next() will read till first spacer in input string.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this will be using **StringTokenizer**. Like this,

```
    inputStr = user.next();
    int index = 0;
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(inputStr, ":");
    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){

        if(index == 1){
            System.out.println(tokens.nextToken().toString());
            break;
        }
        tokens.nextToken();
        index++;        
    }
```

This way you can just get the second string and avoid creating an array of sub strings that you don't need.